# Адресный путь файлов php без указания файла

Tags: php

Добрый вечер.

Как делается такой путь, как например, здесь - http://habrahabr.ru/blogs/    ?

т.е. не указывается никакой файл blogs.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ну там просто `index.php` какой-нибудь, в папке `blogs`. Название `index.php` можно определить, например, в htaccess директивой `DirectoryIndex`.

Кроме того всегда можно использовать алиасы с помощью `RewriteRule:`

```
RewriteRule ^название_в_адресной_строке$ /ссылка [L]
```

Тогда зайдя на `ws.ru/название_в_адресной_строке` вы получите то, что выдаёт страница `/ссылка`, а добавив слэш - получите 404, т.к. директории такой может не быть.

Если я конечно правильно понял вопрос.

Answer (score 2):

Это называется ЧРУ (человеко понятный урл), вот мое решение этой задачи:

1.Зайдите: адресвашегосайта.ru/mod/news/post

2.Смотрим как красиво все получилось

**файл .htaccess**

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule (.*)$ index.php/$1 [QSA]
```

**файл: index.php**

```
// разбираем строку запроса, и формируем массив
$array_url = explode("/", $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
foreach($array_url as $value_url)
{
        if(!empty($value_url)) 
        {
          $SEF[] = trim(urldecode($value_url));
      }
}

// просмотр массива
echo '<pre>'.var_export($SEF).'</pre>';
```